# Getting invalid column name when creating a procedure using multiple if statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

If someone could point me in the right direction.  I have a homework problem where I need to create a stored procedure that takes in a product name and will check how much a customer is spending.  Depending on how much is spent a discount increase will be added to the existing discount.

I've been referencing the videos and SQL scripts provided by the teacher.  I've also checked w3schools, sqlshack, and a few other websites to finish the project and I've reached a point where I'm stuck.  Any of the column names in the if statement gives me an error message of "Invalid Column Name".  If I add the table name to the column, I get a different error message of "The multi-part identifier could not be bound".  I have moved the inner joins to inside the if statements and didn't change anything.

```
    
Use Northwind;

go

CREATE PROCEDURE CategoryDiscount
 @categoryname varchar(50)

 AS

Select [Order Details].UnitPrice, Quantity from [Order Details] 
INNER JOIN Products on [Order Details].ProductID= Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories on Categories.CategoryID = [Order Details].ProductID

If (UnitPrice * Quantity) < 50
    begin
        update [Order Details] 
        set Discount = Discount + .05
        Where CategoryName = '@categoryname';
    end
ELSE IF (UnitPrice * Quantity) between 50 and 100
    begin
        update [Order Details] 
        set Discount = Discount + .10
        Where CategoryName = '@categoryname';
    end
ELSE IF (UnitPrice * Quantity) > 100
    begin
        update [Order Details] 
        set Discount = Discount + .15
        Where CategoryName = '@categoryname';
    end
Else
    begin
        print 'Incorrect'
    end;
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from `@categoryname` and put the results of your first query into variables (declare them above the `SELECT` statement), then use the variables in your `IF` statement - done :)

Comment: Be careful you don't assume TOO much. You mentioned "how much a customer is spending" but your procedure is not specific to any customer. In fact, it considers ALL customers. In addition, discounts are usually applied to order itemss that are "not completed" (for lack of a better term). More usually is the fact that the logic is specific to a single order. Is the discount applied if you are creating an order that contains a item "x" for units of 50? Or is the discount applied to every order that customer (or anyone else) has ever created and received since the beginning of business?

Comment: Do NOT use print to return "information" to your application. It is acceptable for debugging purposes but applications do not expect to receive such information as a "message" from a query. Also, you will need to completely change your way of thinking to be effective in writing sql. [Order Details] does not have a column named CategoryName. You need to think in terms of sets and write a single update query using the appropriate joins.

Comment: And one last comment. `CategoryName = '@categoryname'` does not do what you think. You are comparing a column (which does not exist in the table but i've already mentioned that) to a string that contains the name of your variable - it is NOT comparing the column to your variable. Those are 2 very different pieces of logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should store values UnitPrice and Quantity in the variables, those could be @UnitPrice and @Quantity and it will be in the select statement which comes in the start of your stored procedure. Then use those variables in your if statements.